# Pylance is detecting PageElement instead of Tag in find_all -> ResultSet from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, pylance

This is a fragment of code:

```
def prepare_security_questions(self, response: requests.Response) -> dict[str, str]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    form: dict[str, Any] = {}

    soup_forms = soup.find_all('form')
    soup_form = None
    for soup_possible_form in soup_forms:
        name = soup_possible_form.get('name')
```

The problem is, when i check the type of `soup_possible_form`, Pylance shows that it is a `PageElement` object which is incorrect, it should be a `Tag` object, and because of that `name = soup_possible_form.get('name')` is marked as an error because according to Pylance message:

> Cannot access member "get" for type "PageElement"
>
> Member "get" is unknown **Pylance**(reportGeneralTypeIssues)

I'm working on a project where i heavily use BeautifulSoup and i don't want to use `# type: ignore` on every `find_all -> ResultSet` iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Alright i found a possible solution, i checked the type of each element before all the following code:

```
for soup_possible_form in soup_forms:
    if not isinstance(soup_possible_form, Tag):
        continue
    
    name = soup_possible_form.get('name')
```

But i'm open for other solutions.